# Finding a network switches IP

Tags: networking, switch

These are not Cisco switches or switches with serial cables. They are also on a live 24/7 business network. I was tasked with doing some network work but I don't know the switches IP address and neither do they.

Doing a tracert does not show the switches since they sit in the same subnet IP space. Doing a tracert is just jumps to the gateway's IP.

How do I find the IP of the switches on the same subnet?

Comment: These are managed switches correct?

Comment: The reason I ask is that if these are unmanaged switches they won't have an IP address.  On managed, non-multilayer switches, IP addresses exist solely for management purposes.  They will never appear in your tracert output, whether or not they are on the same subnet as your host, because the switches do not operate on your traffic at layer three.  I just want to make sure we're on the same page as your tracert comment indicates you may be misunderstanding the nature of host-to-host communication.

Comment: Not sure why kind of switches they are atm. So I take it unmanaged means plug-n-go, right? Thus no IP and no configuring.

Comment: Yup, unmanaged means no management interface, just a flat layer 2 domain.

Comment: A switch will only show up in tracert if it's a Layer 3 switch and it's actually routing, regardless of what "subnet space" it's in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scan the whole subnet and look for the MAC address of the switch.  (If this is a 24/7 network, I assume you know the MAC addresses...)

Comment: Like use nmap to scan the entire subnet?

Comment: Nmap or some network discovery tool.

Comment: E.g. ManageEngine is one I haven't heard of before: http://www.manageengine.com/products/oputils/free-network-tools.html

Comment: Any MAC address scanner should do. If you know what vendor these switches are from they should be readily identifiable from the OUI. A MAC address scanner works by ARP'ing for every ip address in the subnet and recording the responses. It should then list every device that responded to the ARP request with the MAC address, ip address, vendor and host name. Here's one I use quite often - http://www.colasoft.com/mac_scanner